# Deploying Express app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I am trying to deploy my express application to Heroku but I keep getting the error that "Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected", but I made sure to define the package.json and the Procfile from the tutorial using npm init.

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "ClassMatch",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Compare Schedules",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/jzone3/ClassMatch.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "example",
    "heroku"
  ],
  "author": "Paras Modi, Jared Zoneraich",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/jzone3/ClassMatch/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/jzone3/ClassMatch",
  "dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "~3.8.11",
    "express": "~3.5.1",
    "hjs": "~0.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

And here is my Procfile, just like the example had:

```
web: node app.js
```

My files are setup like this:

```
/
-node_modules/
-public/
-views/
-app.js
-favicon.ico
-package.json
-Procfile
-README.md
```

Comment: Did you add the files into git and commit them? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#store-your-app-in-git

Comment: Yes the error, "Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected" occurs  when I do git push heroku master after I added and commited

Comment: what does `git status` return? and also `git remote -v`

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn
when I do git status:
# On branch node-version  
nothing to commit, working directory clean
when I do git remote -v  
heroku git@heroku.com:class-match.git (fetch)  
heroku git@heroku.com:class-match.git (push)  
origin https://github.com/jzone3/ClassMatch.git (fetch) 
origin https://github.com/jzone3/ClassMatch.git (push)

Comment: Looking at your git repo I see you put the node stuff in branch node-version so you need to do `git push heroku node-version` to push that branch to heroku. Your master branch is python (I think) which is the one being deployed (reading between the lines)

Comment: Thank you, "git push heroku node-version" didn't work but this did "git push heroku node-version:master" because I needed the branch to be on master.

Comment: I am able to push my express js to git but when i run it in heroku it gives me application error